# Exporting a variable from inside closure in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I have a file that needs to export the output of a command performed by 'node-cmd' package. But `module.exports` cannot be run inside closure. How do i somehow set the closure output to global scope and use it? Simplified not working code example below.

```
const cmd = require('node-cmd');

let node_ver;

cmd.get('node -v', (err, data, stderr) => node_ver = data);

module.exports = node_ver;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the module needs to return its exports **immediately** and `cmd.get` is asynchronous.

Export a Promise instead.